# Powershell change Password of all Users in the Domain

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0

i always get the ACCES DENIED Powershell Error and have no idea why....

my script:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchScope Subtree | Set-ADAccountPassword -Reset -NewPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "Mypw123" -Force)
```

please help me
Thank you

Comment: Does the user account executing the commands have permission in AD to reset passwords?

Comment: So, there's not supposed to be a `$` in front of the parenthesis? I thought it was mandatory, maybe it's optional.

Comment: the user is in the enterprise admin group

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with your script. Things to check:

- Run the command from an elevated Powershell command
- Try with a single user to see if you are still getting the error If it is not working
  for a single user,
- use ADUC (make sure you have launched it as the user launching the PowerShell session), right click and reset the account. You should get the same error.

Comment: How so? What happened when you did #3?